# Regex to include negative numbers in java

Tags: java

In this program I'm parsing input into integers and I can't seem to be able to take in negative numbers and have tried a bunch of regular expressions. I can get positive integers no problem by removing the &&^- it's just the negative integers I'm having problems with.

Example:

```
input = console.readLine("?> ").split("\\D+&&^-");
```

Any idea and what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

Sample input:
-7 * 4

Output:
-7 and 4 should be stored into an array of strings.

Comment: what is the expected input and output?

Comment: input is a string, output is an int.

Comment: I've read regex tutorials several times I just still haven't got the hang of things..

Comment: yes it's supposed to be an and operator.

Comment: I didn't plan on stopping I'm just so completely out of patience at this minute and thought people wouldn't be so hesitant to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` is **not** an "and" operator inside a regular expression. I figure you meant to use `[^0-9-]+`, right?

I recommend *matching* instead of *splitting*. However, neither will trivially solve the corner case of `-12-34` for you. Splitting will give you a single, non-parseable number. Matching with `-?\d+` will give you two numbers, with nothing inbetween (you could treat that as a default `+` though).

Comment: I have read them over and over again. It seems like && is an and operator http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html

Comment: what if user enters `-1-23` in that case your output will be `-1` & `-23` both valid negative integer.

Comment: @LightyearBuzz I'm afraid you're reading over and over the wrong page. Character classes (note the "character" here) have nothing to do with "and" in regexp *per se.* You might've wanted `[+-]?`, but even in this case the concept of "no symbol" is not a part of character class.

Comment: @Anon Christ, try compiling,I said it works with POSITIVE NUMBERS when the &&^- is removed.

Comment: Character Classes are *within* `[` and `]`. There is no character class here (except if you count `\d` - the digits - as a character class). Oh, and note that in java strings you need to double the `\`, obviously.

Comment: I can't tell if you're messing with me or if you don't understand Java. \d and \D are completely different. Where don't I have "?

Comment: Ok, so you meant to split at `[^0-9-]`? That is another option. See the updated reply. Anyway, you ended up reading just a *part* of regular expressions called "Character classes", without understanding the primaries first.

Comment: that works. Have a stackoverflow now but I can figure that out.

Comment: I owe to you that I wasn't aware of `&&` being valid inside character classes, and that `[\D&&^-]+` is almost working. The solution I posted is much easier though.

Comment: Sorry but splitting returns an array of strings. Which can be parsed.

Comment: For the example `-12-34`, that array will contain the original string, which is not a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

`-\d*` should get you a negative integer.  If you need something more sophistocated, such as decimal numbers, have a look at [this link](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=252).

Comment: it will also match `-` in a string like `hey-ho`